# `clear` causes undefined reference error

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, random, numbers

I'm don't seem to be able to generate random number in `C` under `Ubuntu 12.04`.

I wrote the fallowing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
int main (int argc,char* argv[])
{
     int number;
     clear();

     number = rand() % 2; // want to get only 0 or 1

     printf("%d",number);
     getch();
     return 0;
}
```

I named the file "test_gcc.c".

After that I compile it with:

```
$ sudo gcc -o test_gcc test_gcc.c
```

And i get the following message:

```
/tmp/ccT0s12v.o: In function `main':
test_gcc.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `stdscr'
test_gcc.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `wclear'
test_gcc.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `stdscr'
test_gcc.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `wgetch'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can somebody tell me what did I do wrong?

And also how to generate random number in `C` on `Ubuntu 12.04` using `gcc`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use sudo, your plain user account should have plenty enough rights to compile stuff.

Comment: Please post minimal examples, here. If you would have done that, you would have seen that your problem has nothing to do with `rand` etc, but just with `clear`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with random numbers. The problem is that you're linking without the `curses` library.

You need to add `-lncurses` to your `gcc` command line:

```
 $ gcc -o test_file test_file.c -lncurses
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't seed the random number generator. <-- Not the reason for errors

Use `srand(time(0));` before calling `rand()`.

Comment: He still hasn't a program yet - but you have answered his *next* question, "why does my program always output the same number?" :-)

Comment: @lserni: Hmm.. but he is going to run in this problem now!

Comment: @Iserni: thank you both (Iserni and Vinayak), the first program did only generate 1 :)

Comment: I'm upvoting yours anyway. I *should* have seen the `srand` myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `srand ( time(NULL) );` before `number = rand() % 2;` to get different random number every time the executable is ran.

For errors:

- remove `clear()` and use `getchar()` instead of `getch()` and then it
  should worked fine.
- `getch()` is used in compilers that support un-buffered input, but in
  case of gcc it's buffered input so use `getchar()`.

**code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
int main (int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int number;
    srand(time(NULL));
    number = rand() % 2; // want to get only 0 or 1
    printf("%d",number);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 gcc -o test_gcc test_gcc.c -lncurses
```